# Penrose experiment

Tags: quantum-mechanics, experimental-physics, quantum-gravity, measurement-problem, wavefunction-collapse

I just read about Penrose  <strike>interpretation</strike>  theory about the wave function collapse: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penrose_interpretation, which could be confirmed/infirmed by the following experiment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free-orbit_experiment_with_laser_interferometry_X-rays (which they revised as a tabletop experiment)

Anyone knows what is the current status of it ? Is it planned to be done somewhere at anytime ?

Comment: This Wiki article confuses the concepts of theory and interpretation. A theory can be tested by experiment. Different interpretations are different explanations of *the same* theory and as such cannot be distinguished by experiment. If Penrose proposes a test, then his idea is a new theory, not just another interpretation.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense, I'll update my question (though I'll let the link of Penrose "interpretation" for details about its theory, even if it's not an article about an interpretation but rather a theory, but your comment will disambiguate that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This paper co-authored by Penrose explores using BECs for the test: [Exploring the unification of quantum theory and general relativity with a Bose-Einstein condensate](https://arxiv.org/abs/1812.04630).

There is work on these in orbit: [Observation of Bose–Einstein condensates in an Earth-orbiting research lab](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41586-020-2346-1). This BEC lasted for more than a second, as published in 2020.

This paper from May 2023 considers design choices for successor missions: [NASA's Cold Atom Laboratory: Four Years of Quantum Science Operations in Space](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2023arXiv230513285O/abstract). This paper from November 2023 is laying out more groundwork for testing the inreractions of BECs with gravity: [Quantum gas mixtures and dual-species atom interferometry in space](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2023arXiv230513285O/abstract)

So, the experimental work to observe gravity impacting superpositions is poised to go from proofs of principle to practical experimental tests.

Another area actively being developed to test the interaction of gravity and quantum systems, is gravity-mediated entanglement. Eg this paper refining experimental procedure also from last month: [What gravity mediated entanglement can really tell us about quantum gravity](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/375706477_What_gravity_mediated_entanglement_can_really_tell_us_about_quantum_gravity).

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the up to date answer with abundant references!